Is it possible to convert (migrate) tables structure without data from Oracle database to MariaDB using DBeaver tool?
I'm trying to migrate to MariaDB using Export Data option but I'm getting the following error when selecting target container (MariaDB schema)
Mapping error:
Error auto mapping source table "APPLICATION"

Reason:
SQL Error [1220] [08000]: (conn=10) Connection is closed

Could you help me and tell how it can be done using DBeaver or some other tool (database workbench)? I just need the table structure without data.

Can you just recreate it manually? Dump schema as SQL and apply it in new DB.

@talex moved to Codidact Yes, I think I can. The thing is that there are lots of tables in Oracle schema and I'm looking some tool that can perform this task automatically. I performed a similar task when migrating from Oracle to MSSQL using Azure Data Studio.

I believe you can export all of them at once.
